# stack translator in formal languages

Tags: grammar, lexical-analysis, formal-languages

Can someone explain how a stack translator works ? I think it is mainly used for lexical analysis (i could be very much wrong) . Any additional material or links are welcome ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct term for what you are searching for is "pushdown transducer"
See here, for example: http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/theory-bk/theory-bk-threese2.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your question is well formed; lexers don't have much need for stacks.  Perhaps you could clarify the context in which the phrase you are using came up, and why you care.

The closest guess I have is "syntax-directed translation", which generally means a translator driven directly by the recognition of syntax phrases (e.g., text generation procedurally attached to grammar rule matches).

Comment: i have to create a program that "simulates the function of a stack translator" . It should read a number of rows over the assigned alphabet . For each row i should display all the possible outputs. It's for a company and they haven't given me more details.

Comment: Then go to the guy that wrote this spec and ask for more details. With that as a description I sure wouldn't know what to build.